# How to wrap class properties?

Tags: objective-c

there is a conceptional question:
I want to have a wrapper class which forwarding all called selectors to a given object. How do I do this?

And here is why:
I have a library for synchronizing data with a service. And I use Core Data.
For the library I have to create classes of a specific protocol. But I can not use the same protocol for the Core Data subclasses.

My idea is to create a subclass of the specific protocol and forwarding the protocol calls to the Core Data Object.
But there are many subclasses and many properties per subclass and without changing the Core Data subclasses (project specific requirement!)

Is there a way to do this without overwriting every method?

Thanks for your time =)

Comment: Can you try to formulate better the question? Is not clear your goal What is the name of the library you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement `-forwardingTargetForSelector:`. You can return another object to forward unknown messages to. If that is most of what your class will do, you may want to just subclass from `NSProxy` rather than `NSObject.` (`NSProxy` has the advantage that it doesn't implement all of the standard `NSObject` methods, so you can forward those as well.)

One common problem with this approach is that the compiler will complain that your class does not respond to the selectors you're sending it. The usual way to address this is by requiring that users of your object declare it as `id`. This can often be inconvenient as well, so this is a bit of a last resort if other approaches are not possible.

But usually the better approach is to make your class a subclass of the target and add the additional methods required for your protocol. Or you can add the additional methods to the Core Data class via a category.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your specific question is yes. [Message Forwarding](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtForwarding.html) contains everything you need.

I think you might want to step back and evaluate other options. For example, can you add this functionality to a base class instead of a proxy class.